# How do I restore a .sql file backup in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, database-restore

I have a .sql file of the database backup. PostgreSQL is installed in my system and I use pgadmin4 to communicate with database. I want to restore this .sql file using pgadmin. Can someone please guide me.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. A SQL dump (generated by `pg_dump`)  cannot be processed by pgAdmin. You need to use `psql`

Answer (score 1):

An SQL script that was generated with `pg_dump` without the `--inserts` option cannot be restored with pgAdmin, because the `COPY` data are mixed with the statements. You need `psql` for that.

You could use one of the other backup formats ("custom", "directory" or "tar") and use pgAdmin to restore that. But all that pgAdmin does in this case is call `pg_restore`, so you might as well do that yourself from the command line.

Another option is to launch the "psql tool" from pgAdmin, which is nothing else than `psql`. Then you can load the dump with `\i dumpfile.sql`.